# RDLC Show Top border dynamically

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc

I have `rdlc` file that needs to show only TOP border where `Description='Sub Total`. sample data as following:

```
School1 Name Group  
    Student 1  
    Student 2  
    Student 3  
    Sub Total    
School2 Name Group  
    Student 1  
    Student 2  
    Student 3  
 Sub Total
```

so i want Line/Top border on top of Sub Total. 
I tried following code but that puts top border on sub total and every other records after that.

```
=Iif(Fields!Description.Value="Sub Total", "Solid","None")
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

It’s not clear from your question what data structure you are using.

I assume here you are using a dataset that looks similar to the below

```
NameGroup  Student   Val
School1    Student1  1 
School1    Student2  2
School1    Student3  3 
School2    Student1  4
School2    Student2  5
School2    Student3  6
```

Create a Tablix, set the first column to be Student, and the second to be the Val column.  Right click the Row Header and Add a new Row Group -> Parent Group.  Group this on NameGroup.

Right click the Student Cell and select Insert Row -> Outside Group – Below. Set the value of this to be SubTotal, and set the new cell under Val to be

```
=Sum(Fields!Val.Value)
```

Select all the cells in the Tablix, and set the BorderStyle to None.  Then choose just your two SubTotal cells and expand BorderColor to view all the categories.  Set Top to Black.  Similarly with the BorderStyle set Top to Solid, as shown below

[image]

All of this will result in a design that looms like this

[image]

Then when this runs, the report will look as follows

[image]

It’s hard to give more advice with the level of detail currently included in the question, but hopefully this will be able to guide you to a suitable solution.

**Update**

Very similarly to the above, if you are returning the subtotal as part of the dataset, then you can use the properties as described before in a similar manner

With the dataset

```
NameGroup  Student   Val
School1    Student1  1 
School1    Student2  2
School1    Student3  3 
School1    Subtotal  6
School2    Student1  4
School2    Student2  5
School2    Student3  6
School2    Subtotal  15
```

You can create a matrix as shown here

[image]

And set the `Top` `BorderColou`r of the highlighted cells to be

```
=iif(Fields!Student.Value = "SubTotal", "Black", "White")
```

And the `Top` `Border Style` to be

```
=iif(Fields!Student.Value = "SubTotal", "Solid", "None")
```

As shown here

[image]

Which will give a result of

[image]

Hopefully this is what you require.  If you have any further question then please ask.

Comment: Thanks Jonnus.  however my "subtotal" is pulled as part of dataset. it is part of 'student name' column  NameGroup  Student   Val
School1    Student1  1 
School1    Student2  2
School1    Student3  3 
School2    Student1  4
School2    Student2  5
School2    Student3  6
                subtotal  21

Comment: Thanks for updated answer. I applied the same in my code it works but it doesn't reset 'top border' to none for next set of group data. e.g. first set of records "School1" i have top border for 'subtotal', it applies for 'school2' --> 'student1' , 'student2' etc. it doesn't reset to "None" for some reason. I have made sure that default is set to "light gray" as set in your answer above